# Which bugtracker works best with Eclipse's Mylyn on Windows server?

Tags: bug-tracking, mylyn

I have a Windows server running Subversion internal server (1 window service per repository on a port).  I'm planning to add a bug tracker so that I can use Mylyn on eclipse effectively.

[Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)? Seems [hard to install](http://www.tasktop.com/mylyn/mylyn-2.0-part1.php) on Windows

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)?  Does it work well on Windows?

Thank you

Comment: This should be Community Wiki IMHO.

Comment: sure, why not                     .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JIRA works very well there.

Comment: If you're ready to pay, or if you have an opensource project, JIRA is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Trac on windows (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows) should be fine, but you'll need to install Python, Genshi and Setuptools, see:

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows#using-installers

Answer (score 0):

FogBugz works just fine on Windows: [FogBugz 7.0 Online Help: Windows system requirements](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/70/topics/setup/Windowssystemrequirements.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [Mantis issue tracker](http://www.mantisbt.org/) is PHP-based and works nicely on Windows. The [Mantis connector](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mylyn-mantis/) is actively developed and functions quite well.

Answer (score 0):

We're using [Bitnami's Redmine Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) (a single-installer for the whole [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) package, including Apache), along with the nascent [Redmine/Mylyn server-side plugin](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/redmin-mylyncon/index.php?title=Main_Page) and Eclipse.

It's too early to tell how well this all really works, but [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) has so many other useful features (such as a [Redmine TortoiseSVN plugin](http://code.google.com/p/chrismckee-project-bay/wiki/REDMINETSVN)), we're bound to use it.  If Mylyn works as well, that's a bonus.  Obviously we're new to Mylyn and not dependent on it, although it looks extremely useful.

In my opinion, Redmine is much more functional than the other systems mentioned here.  I do not have extensive experience with them, however, so take that with a grain of salt.  It absolutely warrants a close look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to go with an open source solution I'd suggest [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/).  I've installed Bugzilla in a Windows and a Unix environment and found it to be reasonably easy to install in both cases.  The Bugzilla Mylyn Connector is one of the most-used Mylyn connectors and thus is extremely reliable.  I've used the Bugzilla Mylyn Connector personally to connect to my main development server for about 2.5 years and I have been very satisfied with this connector.

The Trac Connector is also robust.  I have recently encountered users who have had problems with it, although I believe these problems are edge cases ([bug 1236](https://tasktop.com/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1236)).  As some others suggest, there are several other options (e.g., FogBugz and Mantis).  I have not had much experience with these servers personally but have heard positive reviews of both connectors and both are actively maintained.

Hope this helps!

David C. Shepherd, Tasktop Technologies

 [www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd](http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd)